# how to setValidators() on multiple formControl at the same time?

Tags: angular2-forms, angular-validation

Is there any alternative method to minimise line of code.

```
 this.addRoeForm.controls.supplierName.setValidators(Validators.required);
 this.addRoeForm.controls.fromCurrency.setValidators(Validators.required);
 this.addRoeForm.controls.toCurrency.setValidators(Validators.required);
 this.addRoeForm.controls.roe.setValidators(Validators.required);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Object.keys(this.addRoeForm.controls).forEach(key => {
  this.addRoeForm.get(key).setValidators([Validators.required]);
});
```